# MATLAB regexp - Return every instance in pattern with unknown number of occurences using 'names'

Tags: regex, matlab, dynamic

I am trying to get every digit from a pattern using regexp. The difficult bit is that I need to use the 'names'argument and the number of digits/fields are unknown.

E.g. I want to match digits in `'[10,20,30]'` with `regexp(...,'names')`, in such a way that the output is a struct with fields `'val1','val2','val3'` (with values 10,20 and 30).

Something like this:

```
>> match = regexp('[10,20,30]',expr,'names');
>> match.val1
    10
>> match.val2
    20
```

Do you know of any way to reproduce something like

```
match = regexp('[1,2,3]','^\[(?< val1>\d+),(?< val2>\d+),(?< val3>\d+)\]$','names');
```

but dynamically, to capture any number (>0) of digits in the pattern?

---

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I want to verify the pattern (digits seperated by a comma inside a square bracket clause, nothing else) and return the digits in the same regexp call.

I could use two calls; first validating the pattern and then returning the digits.

However, my code is expecting one call. For those interested, I want more out of the inputParser object and creating my own variant to it. I have an array of valid attributes to different classes. I want one of these to be the size of the input argument, using the attribute `'size[3,4]'` or `'size[3,4,2]'` or any other dimension.

Comment: Are your strings much more complex than what you've shown here? Because something simple like `tokens = regexp('[10,20,30]', '(\d+)', 'tokens');` would work. Then it would be easy enough to build the desired structure and place the tokens in it.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick to some extent. However, it does not validate the pattern. I could as easily input `(1.2;3someotherstuff)` and this would match the digits. I regard this as bug prone and would like to online match digits seperated by a comma (`,`) inside a square bracket clause (`[ ]`).

Answer (score 2):

That's not quite how the `names` option works. It won't give you a struct with differently named fields like `val1`, `val2` etc. It will give you a struct array, each with a field `val`.

For example:

```
>> str = '[10,20,30]';
>> expr = '(?<val>[0-9]*)*';
>> vals = regexp(str, expr, 'names')
vals = 
  1×3 struct array with fields:
    val
>> vals(1).val
ans =
    '10'
>> vals(3).val
ans =
    '30'
```

If you want to, you can subsequently manipulate this into a single struct with fields `val1`, `val2` etc. But I imagine that's likely to be less convenient than the struct array `vals` that you already have.

Comment: Fair point. I tried to dynamically create the fields, but maybe that is not possible in any readable way. Your solution does have the limitation that it does not validate the pattern, only matching digits in the string. I want to make sure that there are only digits seperated by commas, inside a square bracket clause. Maybe the easiest way for this is two regexp calls. One which validates the pattern (`expr = '^\[(\d+,*)+\]$';`) and then one which returns the digits themselves (your solution, or @gnovice's). However, I was looking for an expression to do them both in one regexp call.

Answer (score 0):

Some time off often helps! `expr = '(?<=^\[(\d+,)*)(\d+)(?=(,\d+)*\]$)';` does the trick, if you disregard my request of output format.

`'(?<=^\[(\d+,)*)` checks for the first bracket `[` followed by any digits seperated by `,`.

`'(\d+)` captures any digit

`'(?=(,\d+)*\]$)'` checks for following digits seperated by `,` and lastly ends with a `]`.

```
>> expr = '(?<=^\[(\d+,)*)(\d+)(?=(,\d+)*\]$)';
>> str1 = '(1,2,3]'; % -> empty
>> str2 = '[1,2,3]'; % -> {'1', '2', '3'}

>> regexp(str1,expr)
ans =
  0×0 empty cell array

>> regexp(str2,expr)
ans =
  1×3 cell array
    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'3'}
```

This both validates the pattern, and captures any number of digits in the pattern in one regexp call.

Then, using the `'names'` argument, they are stored in a struct. However, as @Sam Roberts pointed out, it all digits are stored in one field. Not like I first asked in the question. This is however not important for me, one field with all values is fine.